# Powerapps Get Extended Reports vs Direct Reports

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, powerapps

In powerapps we can get a users direct reports via

```
Office365Users.DirectReportsV2(ID).value
```

which returns a table of users, where we can grab the email or user id for example. This works great as the Items function for a DataTable.

I want to create a global variable on start to load not only the current users direct reports but (this is what it was called in SharePoint on premise) extended reports. So a manager can see everyones records underneath them regardless of how many levels exists between the two.

First battle is I cant seem to copy the DirectReports into a proper variable on start. I tried adding the following function to OnStart (which works for a button).

```
Collect(Reports_1,   
  {
    UserPrincipalName:"All"
  },
    Office365.Users.DirectReportsV2(ID).value
);
```

They show up in the global variable list, with the current column names but with 0 records. While as a button these run and populate properly.

Which to me should return a table array with the direct reports, which hopefully I could loop through, find all their direct reports, and keep going until direct reports for each person is either recorded. Assuming the above collect worked you could run something similar to this

```
Collect(Reports_1,{UserPrincipalName:"All"},Office365,Users.DirectReportsV2(ID).value);
ForAll(Reports_1, Collect(Reports_2,Office365,Users.DirectReportsV2(mail).value));
ForAll(Reports_2, Collect(Reports_3,Office365,Users.DirectReportsV2(mail).value));
ClearCollect(Reports_All,Reports_1,Reports_2,Reports_3)
```

Then I should have a table I can query to see if a record has john@abc.com is a report to a manager.

Comment: Should you have the comma `,` in the `Office365Users.DirectReport()` function?

Comment: @SeaDude No, typo, fixed - thanks.